# How to get GPS coordinate from HealthKit

Tags: ios, healthkit

With Healthkit, it is possible to get heathrate and other type of data.

How to retrieve the list of GPS coordinates ?

Is it possible ?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to query the user's location real time, use the [CoreLocation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation) framework. If you want the locations from a workout that the user already recorded using their Apple Watch, use `HKSampleQuery` to query for the user's `HKWorkoutRoute` samples `HKWorkoutRouteQuery` to get the location series associated with the sample ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutroutequery)).